# Why is my apple seedling turning brown and wiliting

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, plant-recommendations, seedlings, planting

I just started growing an apple from an apple that had germinated seeds inside, and at first it was thriving and growing pretty quickly but now the top part of it is drooping dowards and some of the little leaves are turning brown, the seed had gnats infested inside so I poured 1/4 cup of 3% hydrogen peroxide mixed in with a 1/2 cup of water, and now that I'm writing this I see my mistake. Anyways now the plant is starting to die, and I don't know what to do

I did pour that same mixture inside of a smaller apple that I have growing, and it seems to be doing great

Comment: Can you add a photo showing both the seedling and its pot please, as well as more info, such as whether its in or outdoors, in sun or shade, how often you water, whether the pot has drainage, what soil you used in the pot

Comment: Purely as a guess based on minimal info and no photo, damping off or other fungal problems are fairly common for over-tended and overly-watered seedlings - which is a common fault. You might want to remove it from the vicinity of your other, presently healthy, seedlings; and/or dispose of it before whatever it has spreads.